# Infinite scroll with database queries

Tags: jquery

I need direction to a good jQuery plugin that will implement infinite scroll and will activate once a user scrolls down a certain height of the window. I don't want the ones with "load more" buttons or indicators. There's no second pages to the content, just one long page.

My pages have a lot of rows of data coming from the database so I need something for more easy scrolling. It is just a whole page with a large table so there's no elements I can target as some of the plugins I've seen require.

It basically needs to support all browsers but especially Chrome, Firefox, and IE. Run on all OS. I’m using Symfony2.

Comment: Maybe [Infinite Scrolling with Dates on Symfony](http://www.kadeke.be/en/developer-blog/infinite-scrolling-with-dates)?